# How can I best combine 3 queries into 1?

Tags: mysql

I need the following queries combined into one query that returns the following from all results from the first query you see below (Right now I load the first query into an array in php then run two queries against each result):

- post_id from wp_postmeta
- brandLogoName from brand

Here are the tables and their relevant columns:

1. merchant - brandIdentifier, locationIdentifier, locationName, postalCode
2. wp_postmeta - post_id, meta_key, meta_value
3. brand - brandIdentifier, brandLogoName

---

Currently I run the following and load it into an array:

```
SELECT `brandIdentifier`,`locationIdentifier`,`locationName` FROM merchant WHERE postalCode = '90210';
GROUP BY `locationName` LIMIT 0, 5
```

Which returns:

```
brandIdentifier  locationIdentifier locationName
11111111         666666             ABC
22222222         777777             DEF
33333333         888888             GHI
44444444         999999             JKL
55555555         000000             MNO
```

Then for *each line in the array* I run the following (using the first result as an example):

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'locationIdentifier' AND meta_value = '666666' LIMIT 1;
```

Which returns:

```
post_id
123456
```

Then for *each line in the array* I run the following (using the first result as an example):

```
SELECT brandLogoName FROM brand WHERE brandIdentifier = '11111111' LIMIT 1;
```

Which returns:

```
brandLogoName
file.png
```

I know joins are required. I just don't know how to join to a result set. Can anyone point me in the right direction on writing this query? Thanks.

Comment: Is `locationName` the primary key of `merchant` table (or a Unique key)? If not, the first query does not make sense.

Comment: It isn't. If I don't group by locationName there are duplicates.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see results from 5 merchants that are from different locations?

Comment: I want to see results from 5 different merchants in the same zip code.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of table `merchant`?

Comment: recordIdentifier - Just a unique field.

Comment: It would be good if you showed us the table definitions of `merchant` and `brand` (which are not standard WP tables, I guess they were added by you or a plugin), a few sample rows from those 2 tables and what - exactly - you want as result.

Comment: @nick is you problem solved? Or do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

## SUBSET QUERY #1

```
SELECT
    merchant.locationName,
    wp_postmeta_location.meta_value,
    wp_postmeta_location.post_id,
    merchant.brandIdentifier,
    wp_postmeta_brand.meta_value
FROM
    (
        SELECT `brandIdentifier`,`locationIdentifier`,`locationName`
        FROM merchant WHERE postalCode='90210'
        GROUP BY `locationName`,`locationIdentifier`
    ) merchant
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'locationIdentifier'
    ) wp_postmeta_location
    ON merchant.locationIdentifier = wp_postmeta_location.meta_value
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'brandIdentifier'
    ) wp_postmeta_brand
    ON
    (merchant.brandIdentifier = wp_postmeta_brand.meta_value AND
    wp_postmeta_location.post_id = wp_postmeta_brand.post_id)
;
```

Comment: merchant.meta_value doesn't exist. we're close though.

Comment: Nope, Here are the tables and their relevant columns:

1. merchant - brandIdentifier, locationIdentifier, locationName, postalCode      2. wp_postmeta - post_id, meta_key, meta_value      3. brand - brandIdentifier, brandLogoName

Comment: Am I closer yet ??? (WordPress is annoying)

Comment: I get an error:

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.post_id' in 'field list' 13.260 sec

Comment: Please refresh, look at the query, and try again

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'wp_postmeta_brand' in 'on clause' 4.773 sec

Comment: I corrected it. It is supposed to say `wp_postmeta_brand.meta_value`. Please try again...

Comment: FYI there's no "=" between postalCode = '90210'. This returns a blank dataset.

Comment: I copied it from your code. It's missing there too...

Comment: BTW I corrected it in my answer (I added the `=`)

Comment: Still a blank dataset. :/

Comment: I moved the `LIMIT 0,5` to the bottom. Please try again...

Comment: Still blank dataset. When I run EXPLAIN I get "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"

Comment: I added a subset of the query. Please try the second query...

Comment: That lists 5 post_id and 5 unique merchants. (success)

Comment: Please try out SUBSET QUERY #2...

Comment: 5 post_id but not all locationName are unique.

Comment: How many lines came back ???

Comment: 5 lines came back

Comment: Wait I may have run the wrong subset. Sorry this page is getting complicated.. SUBSET 2 returns nothing at all.

Comment: Please retry `SUBSET QUERY #2`. I hope it lets you see the brand identifiers

Comment: Just retried, still get nothing.

Comment: Please retry SUBSET QUERY #1

Comment: I get 5 unique post_id but the locationName is not unique.

Comment: Perhaps the `GROUP BY` is incomplete. I changed it. Retry SUBSET QUERY #1...

Comment: Same problem. I works when I do:

SELECT
    wp_postmeta_location.post_id,
    merchant.locationName
FROM
    (
        SELECT `brandIdentifier`,`locationIdentifier`,`locationName`
        FROM merchant WHERE postalCode='90210'
    ) merchant
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'locationIdentifier'
    ) wp_postmeta_location
    ON merchant.locationIdentifier = wp_postmeta_location.meta_value
 GROUP BY `locationName`
 LIMIT 0, 5
;

Comment: Each unique location may have multiple brands, so you should not expect the Location to be unique unless the Location is the only column or if a location has only one brand. You should see all brands per location. Please refresh the browser, and retry

Comment: 5 Unique post_id. Duplicate locationName

Comment: Do you multiple brandIdentifiers ???

Comment: I removed `LIMIT 0,5`

Comment: I get many unique post_id. Many duplicate locationName Many duplicate brandIdentifier.

Comment: OK I am trying to attach all brands by location. Please retry SUBSET QUERY #1...

Comment: There's no merchant.post_id. I get an error.

Comment: Corrrected. Please try again...

Comment: Blank dataset. :(

Comment: I am so sorry. I am out of ideas. Since this is a WordPress issue, you should post this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will show 5 merchants, with different `locationName`:

```
SELECT
    m.brandIdentifier, 
    m.locationIdentifier, 
    m.locationName,

    ( SELECT pm.post_id 
      FROM wp_postmeta AS pm
      WHERE pm.meta_key = 'locationIdentifier' 
        AND pm.meta_value = m.locationIdentifier
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS post_id,

    ( SELECT b.brandLogoName 
      FROM brand AS b
      WHERE b.brandIdentifier = m.brandIdentifier 
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS brandLogoName 
FROM
        merchant AS m
    JOIN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT 
              MIN(recordIdentifier) AS pk     -- the PRIMARY KEY of the table `merchant`
          FROM 
              merchant
          WHERE 
              postalCode = '90210'
          GROUP BY 
              locationName
          LIMIT 5 
        ) AS dm
            ON dm.pk = m.recordIdentifier 
;
```

---

This one will show just 5 merchants (perhaps with same `locationName`):

```
SELECT
    m.brandIdentifier, 
    m.locationIdentifier, 
    m.locationName,

    ( SELECT pm.post_id 
      FROM wp_postmeta AS pm
      WHERE pm.meta_key = 'locationIdentifier' 
        AND pm.meta_value = m.locationIdentifier
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS post_id,

    ( SELECT b.brandLogoName 
      FROM brand AS b
      WHERE b.brandIdentifier = m.brandIdentifier 
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS brandLogoName 
FROM
    merchant AS m
WHERE 
    postalCode = '90210'
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Comment: Takes 17sec to run, but appears to work. I'm getting some NULL post_id. I need to see if there actually are any NULL ones.

Comment: There are no NULLS in that table. Not sure where they are coming from.

Comment: If you have `brandIdentifier` in the `merchant` table without a matching value in the `brand` table, you'll get `NULL` in the `brandLogoName` column in the results, yes. The same applies to the `post_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    m.brandIdentifier,
    m.locationIdentifier,
    m.locationName,
    p.post_id,
    b.BrandLogoName
FROM (merchant AS m
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS p 
    ON p.meta_value = m.locationIdentifier )

    LEFT JOIN brand AS b 
    ON b.brandIdentifier = m.brandIdentifier 
    WHERE b.brandIdentifier = '11111111' AND p.meta_value = '666666'
    ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd53c/1

I have create a table structure to test the query, because you didn't supply one. In the future please supply a table structure with sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE merchant
    (`brandIdentifier` int primary key,
     `locationIdentifier` varchar(30),
     `locationName` varchar(30),
     `postalCode` int(5)
    );

CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
  post_id int auto_increment primary key,
  meta_key varchar(30),
  meta_value varchar (6)

);

CREATE TABLE brand (
  brandIdentifier int primary key,
  BrandLogoName varchar(30)
  );
```

I have inserted sample data.

```
INSERT INTO brand (brandIdentifier,BrandLogoName)
VALUES ('11111111',"brand.png"),
('55555555',"apple.png"),
('99999999',"microsoft.png"); 

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES 
("locationIdentifier", '666666'),
("locationIdentifier1",'999999'),
("locationIdentifier", '777777'),
("locationIdentifier", '888888'),
("locationIdentifier", '000000');

INSERT INTO merchant
    (`brandIdentifier`, `locationIdentifier`, `locationName`, `postalCode`)
VALUES
    (11111111, '666666', 'ABC',90210),
    (22222222, '777777', 'DEF',70210),
    (33333333, '888888', 'GHI',80210),
    (44444444, '999999', 'JKL',60210),
    (44444499, '999999', 'JKL',60210),
    (55555555, '000000', 'MNO',50210);
```

There where several problems one is the constant you have encountered. The constant is due to an join in which you combine two table on using different type of values. E.g. varchar with integer values. I would like to suggest that you take a look at the column types. Numbers should be integers preferably and not varchar.